# how to make pivot table using Xlwings?

Tags: xlwings

Would you let me know how to make the pivot table in excel using xlwings?
please give me the sample code
Thanks for your help

I have tried to find how to make it but I couldn't find it

Answer (score 2):

Creating a PivotTable with xlwings is not currently straightforward, and requires the use of the `.api` to access the VBA functions.

An example to create a PivotTable using my mock data in a Table called `Table1` of 3 columns of data with headers: "Colour", "Type", "Data".

```py
# set the kwarg values for creating PivotTable
source_type = xw.constants.PivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase
source_data = wb.sheets["Sheet1"]["Table1[#All]"].api # cannot be of type Range or String
table_destination = wb.sheets["Sheet1"]["A20"].api # cannot be of type Range or String
table_name = "PTable1"

# create PivotTable
wb.api.PivotCaches().Create(SourceType=source_type,
                            SourceData=source_data).CreatePivotTable(
                                TableDestination=table_destination,
                                TableName=table_name)

pt = ws.api.PivotTables(table_name)
# Set Row Field (Rows) as Colour column of table
pt.PivotFields("Colour").Orientation = xw.constants.PivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField
# Set Column Field (Columns) as Type column of table
pt.PivotFields("Type").Orientation = xw.constants.PivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField
# Set Data Field (Values) as Data
pt.AddDataField(pt.PivotFields("Data"),
                # with name as "Sum of Data"
                "Sum of Data",
                # and calculation type as sum
                xw.constants.ConsolidationFunction.xlSum)
```

### Additional Detail

For reason of xlDatabase `source_type`, the VBA documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpivottablesourcetype)

The parameters can be seen in the VBA documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcaches.create).  And [this tutorial](https://powerspreadsheets.com/vba-create-pivot-table/) provides a detailed explanation of these, along with how to change this for different scenarios (dynamic range, in a new workbook, etc.); the guide gives a couple of additional changes to the formatting of the values, such as position of fields and number format.

The options for type of data calculation can be found [here](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/blob/main/xlwings/constants.py#:%7E:text=class%20ConsolidationFunction%3A,4165%20%20%23%20from%20enum%20XlConsolidationFunction).